# boolean indexing on index (instead of dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

When I have a `pandas.DataFrame` `df` with columns `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`, I can filter it using constructions like `df[df["B"] == 2]`.

**How do I do the equivalent of `df[df["B"] == 2]`, if `B` is the name of a level in a `MultiIndex` instead?** (For example, obtained by `df.groupby(["A", "B"]).mean()` or `df.setindex(["A", "B"])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either:

`df.xs(2, level='B')`

or

`df[df.index.get_level_values('B') == val]`

I'd like to make the syntax for the latter operation a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of getting this, both of which look like a detour – which makes me think there must be a better way which I'm overlooking.

- Converting the `MultiIndex` into columns: `df[df.reset_index()["B"] == 2]`
- Swapping the name I want to use to the start of the `MultiIndex` and then use lookup by index: `df.swaplevel(0, "B").ix[2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to grouping by index levels (see [GroupBy with MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex)).
Here's a short, and not very exciting, example:

```
In [126]: df = DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,2,np.nan,6]],columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

In [127]: df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])

In [128]: df1
Out[128]: 
      C  D
A B       
1 2   3  4
2 2 NaN  6

In [129]: df1.groupby(level='B', axis=0).mean()
Out[129]: 
   C  D
B      
2  3  5
```